# lwc component that shows the records of a parent and shows the editable child object records

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, record, table, edit

When I try to edit the January field I get the error :"aura_prod.js:51 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e[vr] is not a function"
I'll show you the code

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title="Lista Commesse">
    <lightning-button-icon
      icon-name="utility:add"
      slot="actions"
      onclick={add}
    ></lightning-button-icon>
    <lightning-button
      label={toggleSaveLabel}
      icon-name="utility:save"
      slot="actions"
      onclick={handleSave}
    >
    </lightning-button>
    <lightning-button
      label="Cancel"
      icon-name="utility:cancel"
      slot="actions"
      onclick={handleCancel}
    >
    </lightning-button>

    <lightning-layout-item
      size="6"
      padding="around-small"
    ></lightning-layout-item>
    <lightning-layout-item size="6" padding="around-small">
      <lightning-input
        type="search"
        label="Search Account"
        onchange={handleSearch}
      ></lightning-input>
    </lightning-layout-item>
    <table
      class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped"
    >
      <thead>
        <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
          <th class="" scope="col">ProjectId</th>
          <th class="" scope="col">Codice Commessa</th>
          <th class="" scope="col">Cliente</th>
          <th class="" scope="col">Referente</th>
          <th class="" scope="col">Nome</th>

          <th class="" scope="col">Data Consegna Prevista</th>
          <th class="" scope="col">Data Consegna</th>
          <th class="" scope="col">Collaboratori</th>
          <th class="" scope="col">Status</th>
          <th class="" scope="col">SAL</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <template for:each={data} for:item="pr">
          <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={pr.Id}>
            <td>
              <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{pr.Id}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{pr.CodiceCommessa__c}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{pr.Nome_Cliente__c}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{pr.Referente__c}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{pr.Name}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{pr.Data_Consegna_Prevista__c}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{pr.Data_Consegna__c}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{pr.ListaCollaboratori__c}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{pr.Status__c}</div>
            </td>
            <td>
              <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{pr.SalTotale__c}</div>
            </td>

            <td>
              <div class="slds-cell-wrap">
                <lightning-button
                  data-id={pr.Id}
                  variant="brand"
                  label="+"
                  onclick={handleClick}
                ></lightning-button>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr key={pr.Id}>
            <td colspan="4">
              <template if:true={pr.HistorySals__r}>
                <div
                  data-id={pr.Id}
                  class="slds-hide"
                  style="
                    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #888888;
                    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px gray;
                    margin: 10px;
                    padding: 10px;
                  "
                >
                  SAL:
                  <table
                    class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered"
                  >
                    <thead>
                      <tr class="slds-line-height_reset">
                        <th class="" scope="col">SAL ID</th>
                        <th class="" scope="col">DIPARTIMENTO</th>
                        <th class="" scope="col">Gennaio</th>
                        <th class="" scope="col">Febbraio</th>
                        <th class="" scope="col">Marzo</th>
                        <th class="" scope="col">Aprile</th>
                        <th class="" scope="col">Maggio</th>
                        <th class="" scope="col">Giugo</th>
                        <th class="" scope="col">Luglio</th>
                        <th class="" scope="col">Agosto</th>
                        <th class="" scope="col">Settembre</th>
                        <th class="" scope="col">Ottobre</th>
                        <th class="" scope="col">Novembre</th>
                        <th class="" scope="col">Dicembre</th>
                        <th class="" scope="col">
                          <div class="slds-truncate" title="Edit">Action</div>
                        </th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <template
                        for:each={pr.HistorySals__r}
                        for:item="s"
                        for:index="indexVar"
                      >
                        <tr class="slds-hint-parent" key={s.Id}>
                          <td>
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{s.Id}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">
                              {s.Dipartimento__c}
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <lightning-input
                              type="text"
                              data-field="Gennaio"
                              value={s.Gennaio__c}
                              onchange={handleContactChange}
                            ></lightning-input>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{s.Febbraio__c}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{s.Marzo__c}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{s.Aprile__c}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{s.Maggio__c}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{s.Giugno__c}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{s.Luglio__c}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{s.Agosto__c}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{s.Settembre__c}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{s.Ottobre__c}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{s.Novrembre__c}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">{s.Dicembre__c}</div>
                          </td>
                          <td>
                            <div class="slds-cell-wrap">
                              <lightning-button
                                variant="base"
                                label="Base"
                                title="Update"
                                onclick={handleUpdate}
                                class="slds-m-left_x-small"
                              ></lightning-button>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </template>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </template>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </template>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </lightning-card>
</template>
```

js

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import getListOfAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/CustomHTMLTableController.getProjectsList';
import saveRecord from '@salesforce/apex/CustomHTMLTableController.saveRecord';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Project__C.Name';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
const columns = [
  { label: "Id", fieldName: "Id", type: "text" },
  { label: "Dipartimento", fieldName: "Dipartimento__c", type: "text" },
  { label: "Gennaio", fieldName: "Gennaio__c", editable: true },
];

export default class ShowProjectAndSal extends LightningElement {
  @track listOfProjects = [];
  @track error;
  @track objectApiName = 'Project__C';
  @track fields = [NAME_FIELD];
  @track referenteFilter = '';
  @track filteredProjects = [];
  @track data = [];
  @api recordId;
  @track searchString;
  @track initialRecords;
  @track open = false;
  @api rec2Id;
  @track contactRow = {};

  @wire(getListOfAccounts)
  accounts({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
      this.data = data;
      console.log('Secondo Compoonent');
      console.log(data);
      this.error = undefined;
      this.initialRecords = data;
    } else if (error) {
      this.error = JSON.stringify(error);
      this.listOfProjects = undefined;
    }
  }
  renderedCallback() {
    console.log("Prjects:::", this.Data);
    //console.log("Accounts:::", JSON.stringify(this.Accounts));
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    const rowId = event.target.dataset.id;
    let btnlabel = event.target.label;
    if (btnlabel == "+") {
      this.template.querySelector(`lightning-button[data-id="${rowId}"]`).label = "-";
    } else {
      this.template.querySelector(`lightning-button[data-id="${rowId}"]`).label = "+";
    }
    this.template.querySelector(`div[data-id="${rowId}"]`).classList.toggle('slds-hide');

  }

  navigateToEditAccountPage(event) {
    this.recordId = event.currentTarget.name;
    console.log('Record Id ==> ' + this.recordId);
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
      type: 'standard__recordPage',
      attributes: {
        recordId: this.recordId,
        objectApiName: 'HistorySal__c',
        actionName: 'edit'
      }
    });

  }
  closeModal() {
    console.log("In closeModal");
    this.open = false;
  }

  reloadList() {
    return refreshApex(this.Data);
  }
  handleSearch(event) {
    console.log('Sono entrato ne metodo search');
    const searchKey = event.target.value.toLowerCase();
    console.log('stampo cosa sto cercando');
    console.log(searchKey);
    if (searchKey) {
      this.data = this.initialRecords;
      console.log('stampo data');


      if (this.data) {

        console.log('if del data uguale true');
        let searchRecords = [];

        for (let record of this.data) {
          console.log('for record');
          let valuesArray = Object.values(record);


          for (let val of valuesArray) {
            console.log('val is ' + val);
            let strVal = String(val);

            if (strVal) {

              if (strVal.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey)) {
                searchRecords.push(record);
                break;
              }
            }
          }
        }

        console.log('Matched Accounts are ' + JSON.stringify(searchRecords));
        this.data = searchRecords;
      }
    } else {
      console.log('non esiste la variabile');
      this.data = this.initialRecords;
    }
  }
  handleContactChange(event) {
    const value = event.detail.value;
    const field = event.target.dataset.field;
    const dataRow = event.detail.row;
    console.log('dataRow', dataRow);
    console.log('field', field);
    console.log('value', value);

    this.data = {
      ...this.data,
      [field]: value
    };
  }
  handleUpdate() {
    saveRecord({ contactToUpdate: this.data })
      .then(result => {
        //saveRecord it's void so. 
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      })
  }
}
```

Apex

```
public with sharing class CustomHTMLTableController {
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
  public static List<Project__C> getProjectsList() {
    return [SELECT id, CodiceCommessa__c, Nome_Cliente__c, Name, Data_Consegna_Prevista__c, Data_Consegna__c, ListaCollaboratori__c, Status__c, SalTotale__c, Referente__c, Contratto_in_house__c, (SELECT Id, Gennaio__c, Febbraio__c, Marzo__c,
      Aprile__c, Maggio__c, Giugno__c, Luglio__c, Agosto__c, Settembre__c, Ottobre__c, Novembre__c, Dicembre__c, Dipartimento__c, Project__c FROM HistorySals__r
        ) FROM Project__c];
  }
  @AuraEnabled
  public static void saveRecord(HistorySal__c contactToUpdate) {
   update contactToUpdate;
  }
}
```